# Operating only on certain rows in a Python 2d array

Tags: python, arrays, list

First, let me say I am doing the [Office Space](https://open.kattis.com/problems/officespace) Kattis problem. I have a 2d array of zeroes, currently, and I am trying to fill in 2d areas of this array as if it is a coordinate plane. So far I have been able to get the list to fill in correctly inside each row, but not across rows.

What I need is to have an operation only happen inside of a range of rows in this array, for example:

```
if "row number" > "bottom of the range" and "row number" < "top of the range":
    do operation
```

I can't find anything on how to do this, and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you post some sample data and the result you're trying to get? I admit I don't quite understand the question as it's currently phrased.

Comment: Are you using Numpy arrays? Check out [array slicing](https://www.w3schools.com/python/numpy_array_slicing.asp) and see if it will do what you are trying to do.

Comment: I really appreciate the quick responses, but apparently I had constructed the array incorrectly, where editing one point edited all in that column space. :p